# Given an outside curve object, how would I fill it with quadrilaterals using geometry nodes?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am trying to make the inside of the curve be filled in with quadrilaterals, using the fill curve node does not work well for me because it creates tris or ngons, which in my experience do not work well with the paraboloid I am trying to 'cast' it to.

[image: Extruded curve that I am trying to fill with quads]

Here is a quick sketch of what I am trying to make:

[image: Filled curve]

Comment: You could use the fille corve and then select all and then go Faces > Tris to quads

Comment: @YousufChaudhry No, `Fill Curve` only works well on the X/Y axis. Unfortunately, that is not an option here...

Comment: Could you sketch the desired result? And please share the blend file with us, because it depends very much on your mesh, which technique could lead to the goal here.

Comment: @quellenform Oops... I guess I didn't read the question properly or didn't understand it. What occurred to me is that the question used this "fill curve" node and could always apply it and use tris to quads?

Comment: @quellenform unfortunately I believe that I cannot share it because I have paid for a few of the node groups that I am currently using

[here](https://i.imgur.com/TCzjAHK.png) is a quick sketch of what I am trying to make

Comment: @YousufChaudhry I would rather not destructively apply any modifiers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you unfortunately didn't describe much, neither how exactly you came to this mesh, nor what exactly your goal actually is, I just had to make assumptions here.

Personally, I would create the entire shape with Geometry Nodes right away.

[image]

[image]

Basically, I simply create a star-shaped structure (as seen in your picture) from a cylinder surface by moving certain points according to a certain pattern.
The structure towards the center remains circular, however, the further out the points lie, the stronger the "distortion".

The shape obtained in this way is then simply projected onto a sphere, so that I get a curvature.

Unfortunately, I don't know if this is what you wanted, or maybe something else.

I still think this answer is nice because it shows some interesting things and you could actually do quite a bit with it.

*PS: Please be so kind and share your blend file in your next questions and try to make sketches as precise as possible. There are just too many possibilities with Geometry Nodes.*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out a way to do what I needed, although it does not use quads, joining a single point curve to the outer curve allows for the fill curve node to join in at the middle, rather than using a strange algorithm to create the fill